# Extending a given cover of a set to a larger set

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Let $X, Y$ be closed sets in a topological space such that $Y \subset X$, and let $ \{ A_{q} \}_{q \in Q} $, where each $A_{q} \subset Y$ is closed, cover $Y$.

Does there exist a cover $ \{ B_{q} \}_{q \in Q} $ of $X$, where each $B_{q} \subset X$ is closed such that $A_{q}  = B_{q} \cap Y$ for each $q \in Q$? I am mostly interested in the case where all sets in question are in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, no. Let $X=\left\{x,y,z\right\}$ be endowed with the topology $\mathcal{T}=\left\{\emptyset, X, \left\{z\right\},\left\{x,z\right\},\left\{y,z\right\}\right\}$ and put $Y=\left\{x,y\right\}$. Put $A_{1}=\left\{x\right\}$ and $A_{2}=\left\{y\right\}$. This is a closed cover of $Y$. Any closed cover of $X$ must contain $X$ as an element since that's the only closed set containing $z$. Since $X\cap Y$ can never be $A_{1}$ or $A_{2}$, the property fails.

This example can be adapted to work for $\mathbb{R}^{n}$.

Comment: How would one adapt this example to the standard topology in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$?